# Как превратить цикл for в рекурсию?

Tags: c++

Например

```
int summ=0, n=6;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  summ+=i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void add(int& sum, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return;
    sum += n;
    add(sum,n-1);
    }
```